# F12 and Ctrl+F5 not working correctly

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, function-keys

When I try to clear the cache and refresh the page via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (or just <kbd>F5</kbd>) I get the prompt ***Type the Internet address of a document, and Internet Explorer will open it for you*** with a drop down list in Internet Explorer.  When I try <kbd>F5</kbd> in Chrome and Firefox it opens the "Open file" dialog box.

When I try to <kbd>F12</kbd> for Dev tools in Internet Explorer, Chrome & Firefox it opens up the print dialog box.

Why is this happening and what can I do to revert it back to the way it was?

Comment: Mine actually works the opposite - if my Function Lock key is NOT enabled, I receive an "Open File" dialog. With the Function key enabled it behaves as I expect, with a hard refresh. Using:FF 13.01, Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000, Win 7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a keyboard with an <kbd>F-Lock</kbd> key.  The function lock is currently on.  "Open file" and "Print" are the meanings of <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> when function lock is on.

So just turn it off.

### Further reading

- Microsoft Corporation (2011). [`Q894513 - Resolve unexpected Function (F1 - F12) or other special key behavior`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894513).  Microsoft KnowledgeBase.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had a virus or hijack.  One thing to note on my Microsoft Digital Media Pro Keyboard "open file" and "Print" are the default when FLock is Not on.  Turning FLock on brings up the Dev tools.